# GestureRecognizers being invoked but not showing date picker using the focus method

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am creating a date time picker but for some reason my tap gesture is not showing the date picker am using for the date portion of the control.

```
public DateTimePicker2()
{
    BindingContext = this;

    _dayEntry.TextChanged += _dayEntry_TextChanged;
    _dayEntry.Focused += _dayEntry_Focused;
    _monthEntry.TextChanged += _monthEntry_TextChanged;
    _yearEntry.TextChanged += _yearEntry_TextChanged;
    Content = new StackLayout()
    {
            
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        Children =
            {                        
                _dayEntry,
                _monthEntry,
                _yearEntry,
                _hourEntry,
                _minsEntry,
                _ampmPicker
            }
    };
```

The code is getting hit but just not presenting the datpicker I think my control might be hidding it some how.

```
_datePicker.SetBinding<DateTimePicker2>(DatePicker.DateProperty, p => p._date);
_timePicker.SetBinding<DateTimePicker2>(TimePicker.TimeProperty, p => p._time);
```

I am using the focus and unfocused events

```
_timePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) => _time = 
 _timePicker.Time;
_datePicker.Focused += (s, a) => UpdateEntryText();

GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
{
    Command = new Command(() => _datePicker.Focus())
});
```

When the user picks the _day entry textbox lets display the date popup for them.
Dayy entry is just a dynamic entry box.

```
 public Entry _dayEntry { get; private set; } = new Entry() { 
 TabIndex=0, 
 Placeholder="Day" ,Keyboard=Keyboard.Numeric, WidthRequest = 60 
 ,HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
```

Date time pickers are declared as such

```
public DatePicker _datePicker { get; private set; } = new 
DatePicker() { MinimumDate = DateTime.Today, IsVisible = false };
public TimePicker _timePicker { get; private set; } = new 
TimePicker() { IsVisible = false };
 

_dayEntry.Focused += (sender, args) =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => _datePicker.Focus());
};
_datePicker.Unfocused += (sender, args) =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        _timePicker.Focus();
        _date = _datePicker.Date;
        UpdateEntryText();
    });
};
```

}

Even if I add isVisble it does not show.

```
_dayEntry.Focused += (sender, args) =>
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
     _datePicker.IsVisible = true;
      _datePicker.Focus();
   });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the date time pickers where not added as children that is why their visiblity is set to false ;-)

```
Content = new StackLayout()
{
     Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
     Children =
     { 
          _datePicker, ** Important these must exist **
          _timePicker, ** Important these must exist **
          _dayEntry,
          _monthEntry,
          _yearEntry,
          _hourEntry,
          _minsEntry,
          _ampmPicker}                
       }
};
```